# Size added to fraction bar

Tags: fractions, rendering

I see that TeX when render a faction they add some space before and after nominator and demoninator, so the fraction bar have width more than nominator and denominator width. The following TeX show this behaviour `\textstyle \frac 1 {\textstyle \frac 1 {\textstyle \frac 1 1}}`. How many space TeX added and/or what constant used for it? I aslo see this behaviour in MS Word and can not find MATH table const that used to determinate this space size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space does not come from the font metrics, it is `\nulldelimiterspace`

[image]

```
$$
 {\textstyle {1 \over {\textstyle {1 \over {\textstyle {1 \over 1}}}}}}
$$

\nulldelimiterspace=0pt
$$
 {\textstyle {1 \over {\textstyle {1 \over {\textstyle {1 \over 1}}}}}}
$$

\bye
```